# Why is my bubble sort algorithm implementation sorting the entire array and skips the first index?

Tags: java, bubble-sort

```java
public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] inputArray){

        for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length  - 1; i++ ){

            int tempa = inputArray[i];
            int tempb = inputArray[i + 1];

            if(inputArray[i] > inputArray[i + 1]){
                inputArray[i] = tempb;
                inputArray[i + 1] = tempa;
                i = 0;
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputArray));
            }
        }
        return inputArray;
}
```

This implementation takes `[20, 35, -15, 7, 55, 1, -22]` and returns `[20, -22, -15, 1, 7, 35, 55]`. Sorts everything but the first index.

Comment: I'm new to Java. What I see here is that in worst case scenario the loop will restart for each element, hence n squared. Isn't that a bubble sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why ... skips the first index?

Because you set `i = 0` inside the loop, but then the loop will do `i++`, so the first element is only examined on the first iteration, not on any "restart".

To restart correctly, use `i = -1` so the `i++` will make restart happen at `i = 0`, not at `i = 1`.

That will make the code work, but it is inefficient to restart immediately upon swapping two elements, because you will repeatedly recheck the beginning of the array.

Comment: Isn't that the definition of bubble sort? It's inefficient and and it checks the array n squared times. Do you have any other implementation of bubble sort so I could compare.

Comment: I thought I had provided a link in a comment to the question, but I guess somebody deleted that. Try a web search for bubble sort, and look at e.g. the Wikipedia article. or the GeeksforGeeks article.