# This sorting algorithm wont sort the last three elements

Tags: java, algorithm, selection-sort

I am trying to find ways to implement selection sort. This following code performs well, but doesn't work for the last three elements of this given array. If this is not a selection sort, I would still want to know why it doesn't sort the last three elements.

```java
public static int[] selectionSort(int[] inputArray){

        int indexOfMax = 0;
        int lastIndex = inputArray.length - 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){

            if(inputArray[i] > inputArray[indexOfMax]){
                indexOfMax = i;
            }else if (i == lastIndex && lastIndex > 0){

                int tempa = inputArray[lastIndex];
                inputArray[lastIndex] = inputArray[indexOfMax];
                inputArray[indexOfMax] = tempa;

                lastIndex--;
                i = -1;
                indexOfMax = 0;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Selection sort result " + Arrays.toString(inputArray));
        return inputArray;
    }
```

It changes this: `[20, 35, -15, 7, 55, 1, -22]` to this: `[-22, 1, -15, 7, 20, 35, 55]`

Comment: I see one loop; selection sort needs two.

Comment: When you have a `for`-loop with a given index variable (in this case `i`), it's not usually a good idea to modify that variable (in this case by writing `i = -1`) inside the loop; it makes it really hard to keep track of what's going on. In your case, your code would be much clearer with two nested loops: an outer `while`-loop that goes until `lastIndex == 0`, and an inner loop where `i` goes from `0` to `lastIndex`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: See my comment. The single loop here effectively *is* two loops. It's an almost-working implementation of selection sort.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Similar to Bubblesort by same author: [Why is my bubble sort algorithm implementation sorting the entire array and skips the first index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57978842/5221149)

Comment: What have you done to trace the operation of your program?  If nothing else, insert some strategically-placed `print` statements to show you what values you're manipulating at each iteration.  That will highlight your main problem for you ... and should be done before you post here.

Comment: Can you word `doesn't work for the last three elements of [20, 35, -15, 7, 55, 1, -22]` differently? The elements of highest index in `[-22, 1, -15, 7, 20, 35, 55]` look to be placed correctly. There are quite a number of details in the code that beg for explanation - let me single out one: What is the idea to have "the `i == lastIndex` handling" in the `else`-branch of `inputArray[i] > inputArray[indexOfMax]`?

Comment: @greybeard My understanding of the selection sort was that you find the highest number and move it to last index position and then change the partition size so you don't visit the last index again. As you can see my implementation takes `[20, 35, -15, 7, 55, 1, -22]` and almost sorts it as `...< 7 < 20 < 35 < 55]`. It stops at 7 and doesn't sort `[-22, 1, -15...`. Why `i == lastIndex`? I am resetting `i` to 0 at the end of every lookup, mimicking a loop-inside-loop solution. my last index is one index smaller on each go so by saying `i == lastIndex` I am controlling when the loop restarts.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when `lastIndex` *is* `indexOfMax` (which in your case happens when `lastIndex` is `3` and the first four elements are `-22, 1, -15, 7`), you never enter the code that resets `i` for the next pass through the loop. Instead, you just continue incrementing `i` (and potentially updating `indexOfMax`) until the loop exits.

To fix that, you need to change this:

```
            }else if (i == lastIndex && lastIndex > 0){
```

to this:

```
            }
            if (i == lastIndex && lastIndex > 0){
```

(I guess the reason you wrote `else if` was so as to skip swapping `inputArray[lastIndex]` with `inputArray[indexOfMax]` when that's a no-op? The problem is that this block includes more than just that swap code, so you're skipping too much in that case.)

---

All of that being said, I feel compelled to point out that your code would be much simpler and clearer if, instead of using a single `for`-loop where you keep resetting `i`, you used nested loops, like so:

```
    public static void selectionSort(final int[] array){
        for (int lastIndex = array.length - 1; lastIndex > 0; --lastIndex) {
            int indexOfMax = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= lastIndex; ++i) {
                if (array[i] > array[indexOfMax]) {
                    indexOfMax = i;
                }
            }
            final int temp = array[lastIndex];
            array[lastIndex] = array[indexOfMax];
            array[indexOfMax] = temp;
        }
    }
```